# NSView Frame Origin Get Reset After Animation Completed (Animator Proxy)

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, core-animation

Animation proxy `setFrameOrigin` makes the view flashback to the origin position after animation completed. I use the code below to animate the `NSView` to move down `-50` points, however, when the animation completed the frame position seems get reset to the `0` and result in a flash of the view.

I have auto-layout constraints set up for this view, I think this position reset might cause by the auto-layout.

```
  NSAnimationContext.beginGrouping()
  NSAnimationContext.current.duration = 0.5
  barVersionFree.animator().setFrameOrigin(NSPoint(x: 0, y: -50))
  NSAnimationContext.endGrouping()
```

I try to set it again using the code below but the result is the same.

```
  NSAnimationContext.beginGrouping()
  NSAnimationContext.current.duration = 0.5
  barVersionFree.animator().setFrameOrigin(NSPoint(x: 0, y: -50))
  NSAnimationContext.endGrouping()
  barVersionFree.setFrameOrigin(NSPoint(x:0, y: -50))
```

[image]

Comment: What does "Animation proxy setFrameOrigin flash after animation completed" mean?  Use the runAnimationGroup method, anyway.

Comment: Update the question. what I want to say is the `NSView` reset to the origin position once the animation is completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's correct. In Cocoa, an animation effect is just that: a temporary distortion of the object's appearance. This can include changes to its opacity, frame, size, transformation, etc. When the animation ends and is discarded, the view object goes right back to acting like any other view object.

If you want to change something about the view using this type of animation, the solution is to:

1. Get the frame of the view
2. Set the frame of the view to where you want it end up
3. Start an animation that begins from where it was and
   ends at where it is now

The view then appears to move from A to B, and when the animation is over the frame is now at B.

Another technique is to add a "did end animation" handler and have that set the frame to its new location, or just hide it.